# If G/H is a cyclic group, then G is a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know "If $G$ is cyclic, then $G/H$ is cyclic" is true, but I was wondering if it true if, "If $G/H$ is a cyclic group, then $G$ is a cyclic group"? I think this would be true since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $G/H \in G$ and since it's cyclic then $G$ must be cyclic right? Do I have the right reasoning/is this this a true statement?

Comment: Well, of course no.

Comment: $G/H\in G$ is not correct. Further note that $G/G$ is always a cyclic group, but not every group $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: It is even not true, if $G/H$ *and* $H$ are cyclic, that we can conclude that $G$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any group $G$ which is not cyclic, and take $H=G$ to obtain your counterexample.

---

For a nontrivial counterexample, take $G=\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ (with element-wise operations) and $H=\mathbb Z_2\times\{0\}$

(i.e., the Klein 4 group and its subgroup of size $2$)

---

The mistake you make is saying that $G/H\in G$, which is not true. $G/H$ is a totally new group, constructed from $G$, but is in no way its element. For example, $\mathbb Z_2$ is not an element of $\mathbb Z$.

Perhaps you meant $\subseteq$, but even then, it is not true. $\mathbb Z_2$ is not a subset of $\mathbb Z$. And even if it was, the sentence "$G/H\subseteq G$ and $G/H$ is cyclic, therefore $G$ is cyclic" is false.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a non trivial example, so one with $H\ne G$, then consider $G=S_n$ (the symmetric group on $n$ elements) and $H=A_n$ (the alternating group on $n$ elements) for $n>2$. The quotient group has two elements, but $S_n$ is not even abelian.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G_1$ be a cyclic group and $G_2$ a non-cyclic group, and let $G=G_1\times G_2.$

The cyclic group $G_1$ is a homomorphic image of $G$ (and therefore isomorphic to a quotient of $G$), but $G$ is not cyclic, because the group $G_2,$ which is also a homomorphic image (and a subgroup) of $G,$ is not cyclic.

In general, if $\mathcal K$ is a class of groups such that $G\in\mathcal K\implies G/H\in\mathcal K$ and $G/H\in\mathcal K\implies G\in\mathcal K,$ then either all groups or no groups belong to $\mathcal K.$